# How far ahead do we have to look after $p_n$ to be sure we find another prime $q$ such that $(p_n+q)/2$ is also prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

If Goldbach's conjecture is true, given a prime $p_n$ is surely possible to find another prime $q$ such that $\frac{p_n+q}2$ is also prime. But I ask: **how far ahead do we have to look after $p_n$ to be sure to find it?** In other words: is it possible to find an upper bound for the value $V(n)$ that we have to add to the index $n$ in order to surely find $q$?

The following are some non trivial "maximal gap" $V(n)$ found:

$\;\;\;\;\;\;p_n\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;q\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\frac{p_n+q}2\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;n\;\,\;\;\;\;V(n)\;\;\;\;U(n)$

$12464401 \;\;\;\;\,12469213 \;\;\;\;12466807 \;\;\;\;\,816565 \;\;\;272\;\;\;(299.4)$

$17806471 \;\;\;\;\,17810911 \;\;\;\;17808691 \;\;\;1139735 \;\;\;273\;\;\;(315.7)$

$42822289 \;\;\;\;\,42828697 \;\;\;\;42825493 \;\;\;2594528 \;\;\;344\;\;\;(357.9)$

$58742287 \;\;\;\;\,58748467 \;\;\;\;58745377 \;\;\;3491907 \;\;\;346\;\;\;(373.8)$

$70196479 \;\;\;\;\,70203103 \;\;\;\;70199791 \;\;\;4128952 \;\;\;350\;\;\;(383.0)$

$82627241 \;\;\;\;\,82633553 \;\;\;\;82630397 \;\;\;4813757 \;\;\;357\;\;\;(391.4)$

$85637311 \;\;\;\;\,85643923 \;\;\;\;85640617 \;\;\;4978617 \;\;\;367\;\;\;(393.3)$

$114736537\;\,114744277\;\;\,114740407 \;\;\;6558493 \;\;\;393\;\;\;(408.8)$

**The last column contains the upper bound $U(n)$ that I conjecture:**
$$U(n)=\sqrt{\log\log n}\cdot(\log n)^2$$

**I ask if it is possible to approach the problem formally in order to verify the previous conjecture.**

Many thanks.

Comment: 1) $2$ is a prime, but there is no other prime $q$ such that $(2+q)/2$ is prime. 2) I think it is consistent with Goldbach that there exists a prime $p$ for which there is no prime $q>p$ with $(p+q)/2$ prime. 3) a rephrasing of your question is the assertion that every (odd) prime is the smallest term in a 3-term arithmetic progression of primes, and you are asking for a bound on the common difference, as a function of the smallest term.

Comment: Andrew Granville, Prime number patterns, Monthly 115 April 2008 279-296, https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Granville.pdf says the strong version of the Green-Tao theorem (given in Section 2.7) implies that, for any fixed $k$, “almost all” primes are indeed the first term of a $k$-term arithmetic progression of primes. Granville makes a prediction for the largest term of the smallest $k$-term AP of primes beginning with the prime $p$, but I don't think it works for fixed $k$.